# XMLHttpRequest cannot load (Soundcloud Permalink). Cannot make any requests from null

Tags: ajax, api, soundcloud

i am accessing the soundcloud api to get the stream_url.
I have uploaded this code to 2 different places:

1) downloads not working + ajax call fails with following error:

- XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://soundcloud.com/woodymusic/woody-heideglu-hen-2-20-04. Cannot make any requests from null. indextest.html:1
- error: error

url: http://download.berlintechno.net/test/indextest.html

2) downloads + everything is working

url: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26890303/indextest.html

Following code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="results"><a href="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/99777114/stream?client_id=fb14c3f2a35b89b556cce18b8614e908" class="btn btn-large scdown">1</a><br>
<a href="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/18658191/stream?client_id=fb14c3f2a35b89b556cce18b8614e908" class="btn btn-large scdown" download="Woody @ Licht&amp;Liebe Open Air, Berlin 29-05-2011.mp3">2</a><br>
<a href="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/11144882/stream?client_id=fb14c3f2a35b89b556cce18b8614e908" class="btn btn-large scdown" download="Woody + Lodig, Weissgerberlaende Afterparty, 1994 - Vienna.mp3">3 </a><br></div>

<script>
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/99777114/stream?client_id=fb14c3f2a35b89b556cce18b8614e908",
      //beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Origin', null);},
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log('error: ' +textStatus);
      }
   });
</script>

</body></html>
```

Is the host download.berlintechno.net affected by any restritions from the soundcloud api?

Comment: `/stream` endpoint is not going to get you data, that's a URL for the actual stream, you could set it as the `src` attribute of your `Audio` tag or object.

Comment: afaik, the stream endpoint refers to the EC2 storage - where the soundfile is hosted.

so i am wondering why i cant download 1 + 2 + 3 from this url:
http://download.berlintechno.net/test/indextest.html

but from that one, its working:
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26890303/indextest.html

That the ajax usage is not correct, yes thats right, but i should get the same results on both hosts. 

Can you check if the origin / host download.berlintechno.net is black listed / has restricted access to the stream_url field?

Comment: hey bnz, the community team will contact you

Answer (score 0):

download.berlintechno.net cites this jQuery library

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
```

whereas dl.dropboxusercontent.com cites this jQuery library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

resulting in differing behavior.

Comment: okay, i played around with both libs, but just click on the links - the behavior there should be the same - but its not. 

on every other host except berlintechno.net its working to download the files.

Comment: Hey bnz. After looking through both sites again, I realized my answer is irrelevant for the exact issue at hand and is likely beyond my scope of access.  I hope the SC team works it out with you soon!